# Tracking down ODROID-xu3 alignment traps

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, arm, github

## I'm using an Odroid XU3 with:

- Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel version 3.10.106-154)
- Clang 6.0.0 (reports `/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7` as the gcc installation)
- architecture is `armv7l` according to uname output

## The issue:

I'm currently trying to edit [coz](https://github.com/plasma-umass/coz/) and everything compiles with no errors. However, running the profiler with any program results in the following error:

```
[ 6325.439410] [c5] Alignment trap: not handling instruction e1932f9f
[ 6325.446696] [c5] ... alignment exception (0x011) at 0xb6f7b061
```

Looking at the core dump which starts at `coz/libcoz/ccutil/static_map.h:17` leads me to `/usr/include/c++/7/bits/atomic_base.h:434` which is this line:

```
return __atomic_compare_exchange_n(&_M_i,&__i1,__i2,1,__m1,__m2);
```

I'm not an experienced c++ programmer or linux user so I'm not really sure where to go from here, is this a bug in the std c++ library? Is there something I am doing wrong here? I would've guessed that maybe there's something amiss in coz's code but the version of coz available as `coz-profiler` through apt runs just fine. I've tried updating/reinstalling gcc and clang, compiling with just gcc, and compiling with different architecture options, all to no avail. Any insight into the next step for fixing this would be *immensely* appreciated.

## Edit:

For clarity, I have not made any edits to the Coz repo before trying to compile it.

## Edit2:

I've tried throwing as many architecture flags at the compiler as I could find, with the list currently being a combination of the following:

- `-march=armv7l`
- `--target=arm-linux-gnueabihf`
- `-mthumb`

I was sincerely hoping this would be just a matter of using the right flags but I don't know if it is that simple anymore.

## Edit3:

I've found the `-mno-unaligned-access` flag and it seems to have solved my first issue but now I'm running into

```
[ 728.768836] [c5] Alignment trap: not handling instruction ed800a00 at [<b6f4ceac>]
[ 728.778027] [c5] ... alignment exception (0x811) at 0xb6f89b63
```